# Removing NULL values from the table

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm having a table with me which has NUll values in a Column, those null values add to Extra Label in the Highchart graph. How to manipulate data using Dplyr to get rid of rows which has Null Values in the specific column?

I was thinking to make changes in the backend SQL queries, and filter the result for the desired output. But it is not an appropriate way.

This is not working,

```
   dplyr::filter(!is.na(ColumnWithNullValues)) %>%
```

Actual code:

```
df <- data() %>%
      dplyr::filter(CreatedBy == 'owner') %>%
      dplyr::group_by(`Reason for creation`) %>%
      dplyr::arrange(ReasonOrder) %>%
```

ColumnWithNullValues <- This column has Null values.

Comment: Do you have `list` column?  What is the value of `NULL` is it unquoted or `"NULL"`.  Can you show the `dput` of a small example dataset

Comment: It is Unquoted, There is nothing in the field.

Comment: can you show the `str` of the dataset

Comment: Is it NULL or is it NA? because NULL isn't supposed to work that way, and your code says `is.na` rather than `is.null`

Comment: I was following the wrong approach, Simply added dplyr::filter( ColumnWithALLValues != 'NULL') and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example df:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df <- tibble(
  ColumnWithNullValues = list(c(1:5), NULL, c(6:10))
)
df
#> # A tibble: 3 x 1
#>   ColumnWithNullValues
#>   <list>              
#> 1 <int [5]>           
#> 2 <NULL>              
#> 3 <int [5]>
```

In this case the most logical might seem to use:

```
df %>% 
  filter(!is.null(ColumnWithNullValues))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 1
#>   ColumnWithNullValues
#>   <list>              
#> 1 <int [5]>           
#> 2 <NULL>              
#> 3 <int [5]>
```

But as you can see, that does not work. Instead, we need to use map/sapply/vapply to get inside the list. For example like this:

```
df %>% 
  filter(map_lgl(ColumnWithNullValues, function(x) !all(is.null(x))))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>   ColumnWithNullValues
#>   <list>              
#> 1 <int [5]>           
#> 2 <int [5]>
```

But as @akrun hast explained in the comment, it is not possible that an element in the list contains `NULL` among other value. So we can simplify the code to this:

```
df %>% 
  filter(!map_lgl(ColumnWithNullValues, is.null))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 1
#>   ColumnWithNullValues
#>   <list>              
#> 1 <int [5]>           
#> 2 <int [5]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `base R`

```
df[!sapply(df$ColumnWithNullValues, is.null),]
```

#### data

```
library(tibble)
df <- tibble(
  ColumnWithNullValues = list(c(1:5), NULL, c(6:10)))
```

Comment: I'm trying to think if there is a possibility of `sapply(df$ColumnWithNullValues, is.null)` returning an incorrect value. Is it possible that an element in the list contains `NULL` AND legitimate values? That's the reason for the `all(is.null(x))` in my answer but I'm not sure if it matters.

Comment: @JBGruber  It is not possible if the type is `vector` of elements as NULL will be deleted.  One option is to have a `list` of `list` of column, but not sure if that is the case with OP

Comment: Great. Even with a `list` of `list` it seems to be no issue.